# Logging in to other wesites using Facebook Account

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I am developing an advertisement site in PHP, the user can only list there products by logging in using there account in the site. Also i need to have another option for users to login into the website using there Facebook account and hence advertise about their products. How can i implement? Do i need to create any application instance in FB for this? I am looking forward for valuable suggestions.

Comment: I suggest you start by reading the corresponding Facebook documentation page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/ - and then search the web - the information is freely available, you just need to search for it.  Please don't expect others to do this search for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640216/create-a-website-to-login-in-with-gmail-yahoo-or-facebook-accounts.

Check this link as it says how to login using other website accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create an app.
- Look into [authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), and see which method (server-side vs. client-side) fits you.
- Once you've implemented that, you can make graph api calls. `https://graph.facebook.com/me` gives you the user's basic details

Good luck.