# how can I add login through other sites

Tags: web-services, web

I saw that in this site you can login through many websites: google- yahoo-facebook...
This would be realy helpful for new users.
So can you teach me how to do this. If not at least a hint.

Comment: please refer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640216/create-a-website-to-login-in-with-gmail-yahoo-or-facebook-accounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is either [OpenID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openid), if you want delegate authentication (reliably identify user) to third parties or [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oauth), if you want to delegate authorization (query some potentially sensitive data about user). to third party site/service, like Google/Facebook/Whatever.

Answer (score 1):

There are two technologies called OAuth and OpenID, 
You can look into

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OAuth_2.0