# Login on hybrid application

Tags: javascript, html, social-networking, hybrid-mobile-app

I build hybrid application with HTML5 base and I need to recognise my user.
i want to use with the social network account (Facebook, Linked-in, Google+), I want to use with HTML5, If the user want to login to my application I want show him page with a number of social networks similar the login process in "stackoverflowsite".

I found a number of solutions like openID. that allowing to user to login with existing account its social networks

I understand that openID is server side but for now i don't have a server it all local on the device.

What is the best way to do this?

Any suggestions...

Thanks for help

Comment: What does "dis also with HTML for all platform" mean?

Comment: these sites all use openId, openId does not require any additional user input, and backend libraries exist. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640216/create-a-website-to-login-in-with-gmail-yahoo-or-facebook-accounts

Comment: implementing openId depends on your backend platform, here are some plugins/libraries for common backends http://openid.net/add-openid/add-getting-started/

Comment: What is mean depends on backend platform, now I start to developer on iOS and i does not have backend (for now will be in the future) i want to save the token in local storage (or in NSUserDefaults)